# Accessibility Service click does not in the expected coordinate

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

So i tried to create an auto clicker with accessibility service in android studio based on this [repository](https://github.com/nestorm001/AutoClicker).

I have the following accessibility service config like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
/>
```

These are the kotlin files

FloatingClickService.kt

```
class FloatingClickService : Service() {
    private lateinit var manager: WindowManager
    
    private lateinit var view: View
    private lateinit var clickView: View
    
    private lateinit var params: WindowManager.LayoutParams
    private lateinit var clickParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams
    
    private var startDragDistance: Int = 0
    
    private var timer: Timer? = null
    
    private lateinit var btnStart: ImageButton
    private lateinit var btnSetting: ImageButton
    private lateinit var btnMove: ImageButton

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startDragDistance = dp2px(10f)
        manager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        view = createView(R.layout.widget)
        clickView = createView(R.layout.edittext_widget)

        //setting the layout parameters
        params = createLayoutParams()
        clickParams = createLayoutParams(true)

        //getting windows services and adding the floating view to it
        manager.addView(view, params)
        manager.addView(clickView, clickParams)
        
        btnStart = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_start)   
        btnSetting = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_setting)   
        btnMove = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_move)
        
        updateView()
        
        btnStart.setOnClickListener { 
            viewOnStart()
        }
        
        btnSetting.setOnClickListener {
            // setting action
        }
        
        setOnTouchListener()
    }

    private var isOn = false
    
    private fun createLayoutParams(custom: Boolean = false): WindowManager.LayoutParams {
        val overlayParam =
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
            } else {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
            }

        return WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            if (custom) dp2px(48f) else WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            if (custom) dp2px(48f) else WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            overlayParam,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
    }
    
    private fun createView(layoutId: Int): View {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(layoutId, null)

        //setting the layout parameters
        params = createLayoutParams(false)
        clickParams = createLayoutParams(true)

        //getting windows services and adding the floating view to it
        manager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        return view
    }
    
    private fun updateView() {
        if (isOn) {
            btnSetting.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.settings))
            btnSetting.isEnabled = false
            btnStart.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.pause))
        } else {
            btnSetting.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.setting_active))
            btnSetting.isEnabled = true
            btnStart.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.play))
        }
    }
    private fun viewOnStart() {
        if (isOn) {
            timer?.cancel()
            setOnTouchListener()
        } else {
            timer = fixedRateTimer(
                initialDelay = 0,
                period = 3000L
            ) {
                val location = IntArray(2)
                clickView.getLocationOnScreen(location)
                
                autoClickService?.click(location[0] + clickView.right, location[1] + clickView.bottom)
            }
            removeTouchListener()
        }
        isOn = !isOn
        updateView()
    }
    
    private fun removeView() {
        manager.removeView(view)
        manager.removeView(clickView)
    }
    
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private fun setOnTouchListener() {
        clickView.setOnTouchListener(
            TouchAndDragListener(clickParams, startDragDistance) {
                manager.updateViewLayout(clickView, clickParams)
            }
        )

        btnMove.setOnTouchListener(
            TouchAndDragListener(params, startDragDistance) {
                manager.updateViewLayout(view, params)
            }
        )
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private fun removeTouchListener() {
        clickView.setOnTouchListener(null)
        btnMove.setOnTouchListener(null)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        timer?.cancel()
        removeView()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

AutoClickService.kt

```
var autoClickService: AutoClickService? = null

class AutoClickService : AccessibilityService() {

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        // NO-OP
    }

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {
        
    }

    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        autoClickService = this
        startActivity(
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
    }

    fun click(x: Int, y: Int) {
        val path = Path()
        path.moveTo(x.toFloat(), y.toFloat())
        val builder = GestureDescription.Builder()
        val gestureDescription = builder
            .addStroke(GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 10, 10))
            .build()
        dispatchGesture(gestureDescription, null, null)
    }
}
```

Starting the service like this

```
val serviceIntent = Intent(
    this@MainActivity,
    FloatingClickService::class.java
)
startService(serviceIntent)
```

The actual result is that, the click is not in the center of the view but instead bottom right of the view. How to make the click happen in the center of the clickView?

[image]

I have tried to get the center x and y of the view but it didn't click. My expectation is the clicked tiles should be the same with the dot view. (I want the click happen in the center of the dot view)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, I also used the source code of Nestorm001.
So the problem is because when we use PNG (circle like you use), and in that custom layout you add the onTouchListener, that listener will absorb the Accessibility click action (If you click at the Center of the view). We still can click at the 4 corners of the PNG because it is transparent, which will pass the click action to the under view.

I went crazy for 2 days and finally figure out the problem was there. So if you want to fix it, before you call the Accessibility to click, you must update that custom layout's Layout Params like this:

```
layoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE; // important - disable touch event
wm.updateViewLayout(your_custom_view, layoutParams);
```

Then when you want to stop auto click, change flag to `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` so you can drag and move that custom layout again.